# MongoDB find() and retrieve only a field of all documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Why does opening this API/test page log the whole documents inside `Users` collection instead of only names?

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../utils/mongodb"

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  try{
    const userNames = await db.collection('Users').find({}, {name: 1, _id: 0}).toArray()
    
    console.log('userNames '+JSON.stringify(userNames))

  }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the output?

Comment: Output is a json array with inside all fields (10+) for all documents in that collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using mongodb v3. While the syntax you used above worked in v2, v3 no longer supports the `fields` parameter. You either need to pass the projection property in on the options object or include a projection document to specify or restrict fields to return, like `.project({ name: 1, _id: 0 })`.

```js
const userNames = await db.collection('Users')
  .find({})
  .project({ name: 1, _id: 0 })
  .toArray()

// OR

const userNames = await db.collection('Users')
  .find(
    {}, 
    { projection: { name: 1, _id: 0 } }
   )
  .toArray()
```

More changes in MongoDB v3: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/CHANGES_3.0.0.md

Comment: Thanks mate! I was looking at the mongodb documentation for version 4.2 which is what I have but it seems to show an old documentation I guess